# Sentence to keyword queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: string, mongodb, elasticsearch, database

I'm building a question bot and up until now i was using mongodb. However i just discovered elasticsearch and it looks really powerful.

I have a database of 'aliased documents' which means that every document has an 'aliases' field that is an array of the possible names someone might call it.

For example:

```
Events Collection:
{
    name: "Birthday Party",
    aliases: ["birthday", "birthday party", "birthday"],
    place: "Tom's house"
},
{
    name: "Bowling Night",
    aliases: ["bowling", "bowling night"],
    place: "Tom's Alley"
}
```

Where my queries will be sentences like this:
'What time will the birthday be at?'
'Where is bowling?'

Aliases are unique within the database so in the above queries i would like it to return the 'Birthday Party' document in the first, and 'Bowling Night' in the second.

I know this is quite complex stuff, and currently i'm using a very inefficient method where i keep an array of all aliases in memory and then search by them if the string contains it.

Is there a query in elasticsearch that could do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need to do all the 'aliasing' as you call it, Elasticsearch has some built in functions that will help you without breaking a sweat!

For example, if you index the following document:

```
{
   "name": "Bowling Night"
}
```

By default the `name` field will be saved as an analyzed `string`, that means that Elasticsearch will tokenize and index it for you, so when you run this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": "Where is bowling?"
  }
}
```

It will break the sentence into separate words and add an 'OR' condition between each word and therefore will match for the document that your indexed. It will also provide a score for the document and will sort according to the score in case you have multiple matches (the more words it can match the higher the score).

Some more info about [query string queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and [Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html)

Comment: Wow i didn't expect that, that's really cool, i can't upvote yet, but +1!

Comment: Just tried it out and i'm blown away, this is absolutely amazing holy crap!